# What data is needed to connect an AC server? Is there any particular format?

Tags: active-directory

I'm trying to create a simple active directory instance for testing. Firstly, I turned on 'Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services" feature (my os is Win8.1). Then using "Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services Setup Wizard", I created an AD instance. Now, I want to connect to it to see available users. How should I do that?

Using the `ldp.exe` program and entering the id and pass of the current windows user, I can make a connection  but it can not bind.

Comment: `Windows 8.1` or `Windows 8.1 Professional`?  Only one of those can connect to a domain.

Comment: @Ramhound I do not want to connect to a domain. The want to connect to the local ad server.

Comment: "AD LDS uses the same standard application programming interfaces (APIs) as Active Directory to manage and access the application data."  How are you wishing to "connect to it" exactly, via PHP?

Comment: Related StackOverflow question: [Is there any free GUI for administering AD LDS (ADAM)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045653/is-there-any-free-gui-for-administering-ad-lds-adam). Also, what actually happens when you try to bind LDP.exe to it?

Comment: Title needs some work.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 No, that is the next step. For now, I only want to connect to the AD LDS using any GUI AD tools. I do not khow how to address an AD instance.